# No data exists for the row/column but exist in sql ce

Tags: c#

**While executing the following code in ASP.NET with C#, I am getting an exception like "No data exists for the row/column."**

```
  private void updateGrnItemDetails(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         txtItemNameGrnUpdate.Enabled = true;
         txtItemCostGrnUpdate.Enabled = true;
         txtItemColorGrnUpdate.Enabled = true;
         String s = cmbGrnUpdateItemCode.SelectedItem.ToString();
         MessageBox.Show(s);
         sqlQuery2 = @"SELECT * FROM item WHERE (itemType ='"+cmbGrnUpdateItemType.SelectedText+"')";
         comm = new SqlCeCommand(sqlQuery2, con_data);
         try
         {
             con_data.Open();
             dr = comm.ExecuteReader();
             MessageBox.Show(dr.GetString(0));
             while (dr.Read())//reading data from rows
             {
                 txtItemNameGrnUpdate.Text += dr["itemName"].ToString();
                 txtItemColorGrnUpdate.Text += dr["itemColor"].ToString();
                 txtItemCostGrnUpdate.Text += dr["itemCost"].ToString();
             }
         }
         catch(Exception ex)
         {
                 MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
         }
         finally
         {
             con_data.Close();
         }
     }
```

**I'm using Visual Studio 2010 and Sql Compact edition. I'm using Please guide me how to resolve this.**

Comment: if it's a `SqlDataReader` you should check if it has rows by `.HasRows` - and either way you should check if the columns are in the select-statement.

Comment: can you be more specific about which line of code is throwing the exception?

Answer (score 0):

You can replace `* with columns name`

```
sqlQuery2 = "SELECT itemCost, itemName, itemColor FROM item WHERE (itemType ='"+cmbGrnUpdateItemType.SelectedText+"')";
```

I suggest you to use

```
sqlQuery2 = "SELECT itemCost, itemName, itemColor FROM item WHERE itemType = @ParameterName";

comm .Parameters.AddWithValue("@ParameterName", cmbGrnUpdateItemType.SelectedText);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your are missing the Read call,before you do GetString()

```
while(dr.Read())
{
  String res = dr.GetString(0); 
  //...
}
```